# Selecting User from a table with LINQ statements/expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Im new to C#, Entity Framework and LINW hope there is someone who can explain something in the code about LINQ. I have a method inside my program that select a user from the table. That method is:

```
 public static cp_user SelectUser(string user, string passw)
    {
        try
        {
            cp_user entityUser = (from u in _db.cp_user
                                  where u.username == user && u.password == passw
                                  select u).FirstOrDefault();

            return entityUser;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

cp_user is the class corresponding to the table I have in my database. And _db is a field which holds a reference to the database instance.

In the select user method I understand that there is a creation of local variable of type cp_user and it is defined by the statement:

```
 (from u in _db.cp_user
                              where u.username == user && u.password == passw
                              select u).FirstOrDefault();
```

1. Im confused about the first part of the statement. "From u in _dp.cp_user". 
   Ive been working with MySQL so far, so its confusing to see this "from u". In MySQL this "u" would be referring to a table. But in Linq im confused to what it does.
2. I do understand roughly the rest of the statement though, that the username and password arguments in the method must be equal to data that is in the table. And that it will return the database object. But again confused about the u, in the last part saying "select u".

Another question I have is in another method called checkany, which check if the user log in is correct:

```
 public static bool CheckAny(string user, string passw)
    {
        bool itIsAlredy = _db.cp_user.Any(u => u.username == user && u.password == passw);
        return itIsAlredy;
    }
```

I understand that the CheckAny methodtakes in username and password and creates a boolean variable which can either return true or false depending on the statement. Here is the part I dont understand.

3. For me this statement "(u => u.username == user && u.password == passw);" looks like it means that the username and password in the method parameters must be existent in the database. But someone at school told me that it means that both username and password must be corresponding correctly meaning; you can't have a password thats connected to another username. So what does this statement actually say. And also again I don't understand the whole "u => u.username". Like what does this u represent. Is it special linq syntax if so what does it mean? Anyone has links that explain this?

Im very sorry if I have made any wrongly statements please correct me if I have im new to programming in general only worked with MySQL before. If anyone could answer the 3 questions I have would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to Get Started with Linq to SQL or Linq to Anything in general. This is too basic stuff to explain here.

Comment: @niksofteng ok thank you very much I will keep that in mind before making another question like this. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "u" you mention is merely a temporary variable that represent one element in your collection of cp_user. In fact it says:

```
for each u in the collection of elements in cp_user do ...
```

Linq has two syntax forms: [query syntax and method syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq). Your statement is a combination of the two. The method syntax has much more functionality, as you can see in the function FirstOrDefault which only exists in Method Syntax.

If you divide your statement into two statements you'll see the part that contains the query syntax and the part that contains the method syntax.

By the way, over the years I've found that proper variable naming increase readability a lot.

(Assume cp_user is a DbSet)

```
IQueryable<User> myUsers = from user in db.cp_user
    where user.username == userName && user.password == password
   select user;
User myUser = myUsers.FirstOrDefault();
```

In words: from all users in the cpUser collection, take only those users where the UserName equals userName and the Password equals password.

From the remaining collection take the first element, or return null if there is no first element (more precisely: return default(User), which is null for classes).

I come from C# world into SQL world, and I found the method syntax much more readable. It helps if you name collection as plurals and every element in the collection as singular. Too short identifiers decrease typing time, but increases understanding time much more than you save by typing the shorter names

```
User user = db.cp_users
    .Where(user => user.userName == userName && user.password == password)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

From the collection of users in cp_User, take only the users with userName equals userName and password equals passWord. From the remaining collection take the first element, or null if the collection is empty.

If you want all properties from the selected user, you don't need to do a Select. However, if you want only some of the properties you'll need to do a "projection" which is done using `Select`

```
db.cp_users
    .Where(user => user.userName == userName && user.password == password)
    .Select(use0r => new
    {
        Id = user.Id,
        Name = user.userName,
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

- For all users in the collection cp_users, take only the user with userName equals userName and password equals password.
- For every user in the resulting collection create an object of a new anonymous type with two properties:

  - Id should have the value of user.Id
  - Name should have the value of user.UserName
- From the remaining collection of anonymous type, take only the first element or null if the collection is empty.

**Any()**

There are two versions for [Enumerable.Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any(v=vs.110).aspx), one with and one without parameter.

The one with parameter:

```
bool result = _db.cp_user.Any(user => user.username == userName && user.password == password);
```

is equivalent to the following:

```
bool result = _db.cp_users
    .Where(user => user.username == userName && user.password == password)
    .Any();
```

In words:

for all users in cp_users, take only those where userName equals userName and password equals password. Return true if there is at least one element in the collection, return false if the collection is empty.

Any is faster than Count() != 0, because Any stops as soon as one element is found, while Count() has to enumerate the complete collection before it compares the result with 0.

You wrote:

> looks like it means that the username and password in the method parameters must be existent in the database. But someone at school told me that it means that both username and password must be corresponding correctly meaning; you can't have a password that is connected to another username.

Suppose you have a collection with two users:

```
ICollection<User> myUsers = new User[]
{
     new User{ Name = "U1", Password = "P1"},
     new User{ Name = "U2", Password = "P2"},
};
```

It is easy to see that there is a user with name = "U1" and password  "P1", but there is no user with name "U1" and password "P2".

```
bool result = myUsers
    .Where(user => user.username == "U1" && user.password == "P1")
    .Any();
```

In words: For every users in the collection of myUsers, take only those with a userName equal to "U1" and a password equal to "P1". Return whether the remaining collection is not empty.

It is easy to see that the first element in myUsers matches the Where, so the remaining collection is not empty.

Result is true;

```
bool result = myUsers
    .Where(user => user.username == "U1" && user.password == "P2")
    .Any();
```

No element in myUsers match the Where. The remaining collection is empty. Result is false.

You see that using proper variable names improves readability a lot. Instead of "u" write "user" and the statement is almost normal language.

If you are going to use linq a lot, consider using the method syntax instead of query syntax. The method syntax has a lot more functionality than query syntax. Method syntax is more basic C#. Using method syntax you can also add your own LINQ-like functions. So if you will be using Linq a lot, consider learning the Method syntax.

See: [Extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

1. The `u` in `from u in _db.cp_user` is a reference to each item in the list that matches the condition (i.e. `u.username == user && u.password == passw`).
2. `select u` returns the matching items.
3. The statement will return true only if there's an entry in the database where both the username and password matches the supplied parameters.

Here's a good place to start learning about LINQ: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq

Comment: Thanks very much I will start immediately!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> from u in _db.cp_user
> where u.username == user && u.password == passw
> select u
> ```

LINQ has it's own syntax and like any other thing you will have to learn and get used to it eventually. Do not mix up SQL and LINQ query syntaxes. The `u` in this query is a range variable. You can think of `u` as an table alias that we use in SQL queries on which `where` clause is applied. Note that I said so just for your easier understanding. That does not mean the above code when translated to equivalent SQL actually uses `u` as an alias.

> _db.cp_user.Any(u => u.username == user && u.password == passw)

The code inside `Any` function is lambda expression. You need to learn about them too. They are beautiful and reduce your code like anything. See below

`Any` is an extension method with definition as:

```
static bool Any<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate) {
    foreach (T element in source) {
        if (predicate(element)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

`predicate` parameter here is delegate that represents a method which represents a method which accepts `T` type of input parameter and returns `bool`. So if you want to write same code without lambda expression you would have to define a method like this

```
private bool CheckUser(cp_user user, string user, string passw) {
    if (user.username == user && cp_user.password == passw) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and use this method as predicate to filter out invalid users. That's lot of unnecessary work.

I hope you are now convinced and motivated enough to learn more on lambdas.